# how to change the format of the columns of csv exported- laravel excel

Tags: laravel, csv, laravel-excel

I exported a csv file with `laravel-excel 3.1` and when reviewing the values are enclosed in quotes, so they are exported as strings, but I need it to be in type number

Exported csv file:

```
"ano_plantacion","zona","sitio","manejo","sup_ha","codigo","rpend"
"2018","87","3","10","30.69","2042201801",""
"2017","87","3","10","14.86","2042201701",""
```

What I want or should be:

```
ano_plantacion,zona,sitio,manejo,sup_ha,codigo,rpend
2018,87,3,10,30.69,2042201801,
2017,87,3,10,14.86,2042201701,
```

Class SuperImport:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Super;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;


class SuperExport implements FromCollection,WithHeadings, WithColumnFormatting
{
    use Exportable;

    protected $superficie;

    public function __construct($superficie = null)
    {
        $this->superficie = $superficie;
    }
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'ano_plantacion',
            'zona',
            'sitio',
            'manejo',
            'sup_ha',
            'codigo',
            'rpend',

        ];
    }

    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'A' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL,
            'B' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL,
            'C' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL,
            'D' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL,
            'E' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL,
            'F' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL,
            'G' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL,
        ];
    }

    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->superficie ?: Super::all();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
$super = Super::select('ano_plantacion','zona','sitio', 'manejo','sup_ha','codigo','rpend')->get();
Excel::store( new SuperExport($super), 'export/Super.csv' );
```

It is assumed that with the `columnFormats()` method it is possible to change the format, but I don't see in the documentation what format is available, and when executing the code the problem continues.

Help pls :(

Comment: I Find the formats https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.11.0/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Style/NumberFormat.html, and change to FORMAT_NUMBER and continue exporting with quotes :(

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, instead of using laravel excel, I tried another library: https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel

So was my controller:

```
  (new FastExcel(Super::all()))->export(storage_path('app/export/SuperFast.csv'), function ($super) {
      return [
          'ano_plantacion' => $super->ano_plantacion,
          'zona' => $super->zona,
          'sitio' => $super->sitio,
          'manejo' => $super->manejo,
          'sup_ha' => $super->sup_ha,
          'codigo' => $super->codigo,
          'repend' => $super->repend,
      ];
  });
```

This is how my csv was: http://prntscr.com/squjh5